# Show that $ImT^t=(kerT)°$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V→W$ be linear transformation and V have a finite dimension. Show that $ImT^t=(kerT)°$

I have to prove it by mutual inclusion. I have proven the first inclusion but I don't know how to prove that $(kerT)°$ is contained in $ImT^t$.

And I don't know the theory for orthogonal complements yet, so the problem has to be solved using the inclusions I mentioned or dimensions.

It's the problem number 11.38 in the Schaum's Outline for Linear Algebra by S. Lipschutz, and the theory I have to use has to be what's given until the chapter 11 of that book.

Comment: There's a very recent deleted question, closed as a duplicate, with the same title and problem statement: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169792/show-that-imtt-kert%c2%b0. Can a 10k user take a look at it?

Comment: It was my question, but the question it was marked as a duplicate of was about ortogonal complements, which doesn't solve my question. So I reformulated it as it's advised when a question is marked as a duplicate and not solved, and deleted the other one.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g\in \ker(T)^{\circ}$, then
$$
\forall x\in V, Tx = 0 \Rightarrow g(x) = 0
$$
Hence, we get a well-defined map
$$
f : \text{Im}(T) \to \mathbb{C} \text{ given by } Tx \mapsto g(x)
$$
Extend $f$ trivially to the rest of $W$ to get $f \in W^{\ast}$ which satisfies $T^t(f) = g$. Hence,
$$
\ker(T)^{\circ} \subset \text{Im}(T^t)
$$

Comment: What does "extend $f$ trivially" mean? Set $f(w)=0$ when $w\notin\text{im}\,T$? Then linearity of $f$ on all of $W$ is not clear to me. (It seems to fail when you apply $f$ to a sum where one addend is in the image of T and the other isn't.)

Comment: You extend a basis of $\text{Im}(T)$ to all of $W$ and extend $f$ so that it is zero on the subset of that basis that it $\notin \text{Im}(T)$.